# C# check if Form was opened with arguments when button is clicked

Tags: c#

I want to re-use a Form, and the behaviour of a button should change, depending if the form was opened with arguments or not.
The form is opened with this code:

```
public partial class FollowUp : Form
{
    public FollowUp(string so)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    [code]
    }
}
```

and outside the form code is the button click code:

```
private void btnSaveChanges_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (string so != "")
    {
        some code
    }
}
```

How can I get the button click event to recognize if there was an argument when opening the form? (the string 'so' is not recognized in the button code).

Comment: You need to store string so in your Form's class as a member. This is a pretty basic question, so I suggest you read a little about object oriented programming. Hope that doesn't come across as patronizing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, your `FollowUp` class could be defined as

```
public partial class FollowUp : Form
{
    private string _So;

    public FollowUp(string so)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _So = so;
        [code]
    }

    private void btnSaveChanges_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_So != "")
        {
            some code
        }
    }
}
```

Key idea: store your `so` variable passed in coustructor into class private field `_So` and use this sotred value when it is needed.

Comment: So if I open the form with:
FollowUp followup = new FollowUp(celleverdi);
the string celleverdi will be recognized as so later?

Comment: Wait a bit... it looks like I've slightly misunderstood your question. Is `btnSaveChanges_Click` method located outside `FollowUp` class?